# How can I access the Apache server configuration in a BEGIN block in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, apache2, startup, mod-perl2

I've been trying to switch from using PerlSetEnv to using [custom configuration directives](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/custom.html).  I have my configuration module with a copy of `set_val` from the docs:

```
sub set_val
{
    local our ($key, $self, $parms, $arg) = @_;
    $self->{$key} = $arg;
    unless ($parms->path)
    {
        local our $srv_cfg = Apache2::Module::get_config($self, $parms->server);
        $srv_cfg->{$key} = $arg;
    }
}
```

...which is called by every custom directive sub.  Then I have in my .conf:

```
PerlLoadModule MyModule::ServerConfig
MyCustomDirective 'hello'
```

This works fine in that httpd -t okays the file's syntax.  The problem is that I can't seem to get at the value from the config file from within a BEGIN block, which I need to do.

I've tried tinkering with all sorts of things:

```
BEGIN
{
    use Apache2::CmdParms ();
#   use Apache2::Directive ();
    use Apache2::Module ();
#   use Apache2::ServerUtil ();
#   use Apache2::RequestUtil ();

    use Data::Dump;
    warn ddx(Apache2::Module::get_config('MyModule::ServerConfig', Apache2::CmdParms->server));
#   warn ddx(Apache2::Directive->as_hash);
#   warn Apache2::ServerUtil->dir_config('MyCustomDirective);
#   warn Apache2::CmdParms->server->server_hostname();
}
```

...but to no avail.  Most of my efforts (trying to access `CmdParms->server` for instance) result in `Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting` and an automatic restart of Apache as it says.  If I pass `ServerUtil->server to get_config()`, the server stays alive but the warning only prints out '1'.

I read somewhere that this is because you can't get at anything request-related within a `BEGIN` block, because requests vary.  It kind of makes sense, except that with PerlOptions +GlobalRequest I have been able to see `$ENV` within a `BEGIN` block, so why wouldn't I be able to see my own directives, just as dependent as they are on how the request happens?  Especially confusing is that if I try to pass `Apache2::RequestUtil->request->per\_dir\_config()` to `get_config()`, it says `Global $r object is not available.`  If that's true in a `BEGIN` block, how is it I can get at `$ENV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partly, Dump isn't being used correctly.  This works better:

```
use Data::Dump qw(pp);
warn pp(Apache2::Module::get_config('MyModule::ServerConfig', Apache2::ServerUtil->server));
```

However, it doesn't show any directives that appear within <Directory> blocks.

In my particular case, though, I don't need that functionality, on second thought; that just happens to be where I had stuck them.

Answer (score 0):

Try add what you want to `import` function to other module and `use` this module in code where you usually put `BEGIN` block. It should work same. May be it helps.

Comment: when you wrote `use Module;` it works like `BEGIN {require Module; Module->import();}` Instead using `BEGIN` block you can make `Module` with work what you want inside `BEGIN` block in module body or its import function. Its more worth approach than using `BEGIN` block. Less magic.